# Django Rest Framework - Updating a ForeignKey Field entry in the view

Tags: django-rest-framework, foreign-keys

In my `Django Rest Framework` project, I have a `ForeignKey` relationship between two models:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    ...
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    ...

class Category(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
```

As you can see, a `Book` *can* belong to a `Category` but *it does not have to*. That means the '`category`' field could be null.
So, in my `views.py`, any `Book` instance can be updated/patched if the user wants to assign a certain `Book` to a particular `Category`. That `views.py` update method looks like this:

```
class UpdateBooksCategory(generics.GenericAPIView):
    '''
        Class-based view to update the 'category' field of a Book instance.
    '''
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def patch(self, request,*args, **kwargs):
        # get the Book instance first
        book = Book.objects.get(pk=request.data.get('bookId'))

        # if it is not assigned to a Category, then assign it
        if book and not book.category:
            book.category = Category.objects.get(name=request.data.get('categoryName'))
            book.save()

            serializer = self.get_serializer(book, context={"request": request})
    
            return Response(serializer.data)
            
        # otherwise, return a generic response
        return Response({'response': "You have already put the selected Book in a Category."})
```

If you can see, first I get the `Book` instance that the user wants to update by using the `Book`'s ID. If its `Category` field is not already filled, I get a `Category` instance using the given category name and assign it.

For the sake of completeness, here are my serializer classes:

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ['id', 'name']


class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ['id', /*some other fields*/,..., 'category']
```

So, finally my question: I wanted to know if this is the preferred way of updating a `ForeingKey` field like this? I mean looking at the `UpdateBooksCategory` class-based view, is this the right way of doing it? The code works ( I tested it with PostMan) but since I am new to DRF I wanted to know if such an updating process is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your `BookSerializer`:

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category_id = serializers.IntegerField(write_only=True)
    category = CategorySerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = [
            'id',
            # some other fields,
            'category',
            'category_id',
        ]
```

`category` will be a nested data that is read only, then setting the category will be by including the `category_id` in your requests.